# How to convert <pre> tag to HTML using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to convert Pre to html  below is my pre tag

```
<pre>
   Point1
   Point2
   Point3
</pre>
```

I am expecting output in html in ul li format like below

- Point1
- Point2
- Point3

Comment: string replacement?

Comment: What have you tried yourself to achieve this?

Comment: post your code...

Answer (score 5):

1) Grab the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the `<pre>` element

and then chain the following methods:

2)  [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) the surrounding space

3) [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) against the line return

4) [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over that array and return an array of list items (using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)), and finally

5) [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) that up into a string.

Then simply add the HTML string to the DOM ([`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML))

```js
const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
const items = pre.textContent.trim().split(/\n/).map(el => `<li>${el}</li>`).join('');
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<ul>${items}</ul>`);
```

```html
<pre>
   Point1
   Point2
   Point3
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `pre` text content and split it by the `\n` (line feed)...
Then create the `<ul>`/`<li>` structure like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var text = $("pre").text();
  var lines = text.split("\n");
  
  var ul = $("<ul>");
  
  for(i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
    if(lines[i]!=""){
      var li = $("<li>").text(lines[i]);
      ul.append(li);
    }
  }
  
  $("pre").remove();
  $("body").append(ul);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre>
   Point1
   Point2
   Point3
</pre>
```

So once you have a text array, you just have to loop through it to create the list elements and append it to the `body` or any other container.

Comment: note that this sollution uses JQuery and not plain JS